# Angular 7 - Nav Child component display router-outlet vs iframe

Tags: angular2

I have created a Angular 7 web app data-driven display of navigation items and content to be shown when a nav item is selected.

I have the following nav item interface:

```
interface NavItem {
  title: string;
  icon: string;
  link: string;
  pages?: NavItem[];
}
```

Where it can be implemented like so for an Angular route:

```
title: 'Home',
icon: 'faCoffee', // from Material CSS
link: '/home', // Notice it is an Angular route
pages: null
```

Or like this:

```
title: 'Company Name',
icon: 'faCompany',
link: 'http://subdomain.company.com', // Notice it is an external URI
pages: null
```

I have the following in **nav.component.html**:

```
<div *ngFor="let navItem of navItems">     

<!-- use a simple div for an item that has no children,
        match up the styling to the expansion panel styles -->
      <div class="nav-head" *ngIf="navItem.pages === null">
        <a class="nav-link"
          (click)="changeLink(navItem.link)" // (1)
          routerLinkActive="selected">
          <mat-icon>{{navItem.icon}}</mat-icon>
          <span class="nav-link-text">{{navItem.title}}</span>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>

<app-content-display [hyperlink]="rawLink"></app-content-display> // (2)
```

In **nav.component.ts**

```
export class NavComponent {
  rawLink: string = "/";

  public navList: NavItem[];

  changeLink(link: string){ // (1)
    this.rawLink = link;
  }
}
```

app-content-display directive is defined like so:

**content-display.component.ts**:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-content-display', // (2)
  templateUrl: './content-display.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./content-display.component.scss']
})
export class ContentDisplayComponent implements OnInit {

  private _link = '';
  isAngularLink = true;

  @Input()
  set hyperlink(hyperlink: string){ // When a setter is triggered by (1), the value is checked to determine if it is an Angular route. The output then decides whether to show an angular router-outlet or to show an iframe.
    this._link = hyperlink;
    this.isAngularLink = this.checkIfAngularLink();

    if(this.isAngularLink){
      this.router.navigate([`${this._link}`]);
    }
  }

  get hyperlink(): string{
    return this._link;
  }

  trustedLink = () => {
    return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(this.hyperlink); // Has to be a function as opposed to a property that gets
  } 

  constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer, private router: Router ) {  }

  ngOnInit() {}

  checkIfAngularLink(){

    if(this._link.indexOf('company.com') > 0){
      return false;
    }

    return true;
  }
}
```

On **content-display.component.html**:

```
<div *ngIf="isAngularLink">
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>

<div *ngIf="!isAngularLink">
  <iframe [src]="trustedLink()" width="100%" height="800px"></iframe>
</div>
```

**The end result is**:

The parent component (nav.component) shows a child component (content-display.component). When a link is clicked on parent component, the child component's hyperlink property receives the link, checks if it is an Angular route vs external resources.

1. If a user clicks on a navigation link that points to an internal Angular page, router-outlet will show the output
2. If a user clicks on a navigation link that points to an external URI, an iframe will be called to show the output.

I feel that child component (content-display.component) may know (i.e. not obeying SRP) and do too much and may need refactoring. However, I don't anticipate child component will be reused by other areas of the web app. Any thoughts on the architecture of my navigation components?